# Store REST query parameters as static fields

Tags: java, rest

Is it a good practice to store the query parameters as static fields to handle a request? For instance, my endpoint accepts two query parameters. To validate and process the request body, I have to pass these query parameters to all the low-level methods (like daisy-chaining). To avoid this, I can store these parameters as static fields within a static class and access these parameters whenever required instead of passing it around. I am fairly new to REST development and I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there are existing patterns to handles the problem I facing. Any thoughts on my approach?

In the code below, I am passing query1, query2, query3 parameters to validateRequest API, which is again passing some of the query parameters to its internal methods. This daisy-chaining will continue to low-level methods. My question is if store these query parameters in a static class, I don't have to pass the query parameters around. When an API requires query parameters, it can call the static class to access the parameters.
Pseudocode:

```
public class Temp {

  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

  public Response post(
      @QueryParam("query1")  final String query1,
      @QueryParam("query2") final String query2,
      @QueryParam("query3") final String query3,
      final Object requestBody) {

    validateRequest(requestBody,query1,query2,query3)

    return Response.status(Status.OK).build();

  }

  private void validateRequest(Object requestBody, String query1, String query2, String query3) {

    validateFirstPartOfRequest(requestBody,query1);
    validateSecondPartOfRequest(requestBody,query1,query2);
    validateThirdPartOfRequest(requestBody,query1),query3;
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a pseudocode example?

Comment: "passing" data to methods by static variables isn't any good. Don t do this. 2, 3 parameters is ok to pass to methods (and probably service layer). Anything else create DTO class (and DTO object on demand) to communicate.

Comment: Thank you @PeterMmm. I appreciate your response.

Comment: @sigur I added the pseudocode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`To validate and process the request body, I have to pass these query parameters to all the low-level methods` I'm not affraid by this. For instance request parameters will be used for filtering a collection ressource so it sounds logic to pass these parameters until the data access layer for applying your filters at database-level (criteria query).

If you have lot of parameters just wrap them into a parameter object (https://refactoring.guru/introduce-parameter-object)

Regarding static it is really a bad idea. Static data will be shared by all requests(threads) coming to your controller and so you'll face some overlap between values.

It's not recommended to change a static variable from multiple threads just to avoid carrying it in the class instance, but if that's what you want to do, maybe you should have a look at `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. After reading your comment, I am leaning towards passing the parameters around.